# How can the output of a `type()` function have a new input?

Tags: python, oop, types, properties, descriptor

I'm reading an docs about Descriptors in [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties)

The doc explains property function in terms of descriptor protocols.

And it emulates the `PyProperty_Type()` in python.

```py
class Property:
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc
        self._name = ''

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"property '{self._name}' has no getter")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"property '{self._name}' has no setter")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"property '{self._name}' has no deleter")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        prop = type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
        prop._name = self._name
        return prop

    def setter(self, fset):
        prop = type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
        prop._name = self._name
        return prop

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        prop = type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
        prop._name = self._name
        return pro
```

I have a question about `type()` in `getter()`, `setter()` and `deleter()`.

*How does the `type()` function get inputs like that?*

As far as I know, `type()` only return the type of the input, literally. My expectation of `type(self)` is a type class (e.g. '<class 'type'>') not a class or instance itself.

~But here the `type(self)` get inputs same as the original class, which seems weird. I believe here `type(self)` should be change to `self`.~ This is a wrong statement.

For example,

```py
l = [1,2,3]
x = type(l)
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

the results of above code are shown below.

```py
<class 'list'>
<class 'type'>
```

And if I add input like below,

```py
l = [1,2,3]
x = type(l)([1,2])
print(x)
```

output is

```py
[1, 2]
```

Hopely someone anwsers this question. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but `type(instance)` returns the class of that instance, and `type(MyClass)` returns `type`. In the above code `self` is an instance of a `Property` (or a subclass of it) so `type(self)` returns the `Property` class. I don't understand why you expect `self` to be a class and not an instance.

Comment: `self` is an instance here. Why do you expect `type(self)` to return a type class object instead of a class object?

Comment: @MechanicPig @Selcuk Oh, I made the question unclear. Sorry. At first, I thought that the `type(self)` should be `self` to have such an input, but `self` is an instance which means it doesn't make sense. This statement is invalid. Thank you all for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

`type(self)` returns the type of the current object referred by self - that is the class of the object - in this code, it would be the same as using `Property` - and then you simply call the object class - i.e. property, with the new parameters.

In other words so that it is clear:
`type(self)` returns the class of "self", in this case "Property". It also could be written as `self.__class__` or spelled out explicitly as `Property`.
The immediately following parenthesis group, as in the line `prop = type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)` will simply call the class with this new set of parameters, producing a new instance. (In Python the syntax and semantics for creating a new instance and calling a class are the same).

The reason for using it in this way rather than just hardcoding the name "Property" is because in this way it will work if one subclasses the class "Property" defined here, and the code will work as is with any subclasses, as `type(self)` will return the subclass, which will then be used to create the new instance.

An advice I can give you: Python is a great language to learn if you use it a bit in the interactive mode, rather than relying solely on the output of complete programs - if you can go into an interactive mode and type the following, and see this happening by yourself, it might be much easier to understand these concepts:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("creating new instance of A")
... 
>>> a = A()
creating new instance of A
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type(a)()
creating new instance of A
<__main__.A object at 0x...>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer even though it is an unclear question. I lacked an understanding of type functions. Thanks for the additional advise :)